# How do you pass String value using button from one activity to two different activities?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-edittext

I would like to pass a value that I get from an EditText to two activities with a click of a button. I managed to pass the value to one activity, displaying it in textview and i would like to do the same to another activity but I'm not sure if switch case is the right method to use since there's only one button.

This is the codes for the first activity:

```
public class ProfInfo1 extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.profinfo1);


    final EditText et0 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.et_name);
    final EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.et_age);
    final EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.et_height);
    final EditText et3 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.et_weight);

    Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_back1);
    back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent a = new Intent(ProfInfo1.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(a);
    }

    });

    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next1);
    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(ProfInfo1.this, ViewProf1.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", et0.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("age", et1.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("height", et2.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("weight", et3.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});


}   
}
```

This is the second activity where the values are displayed:

```
public class ViewProf1 extends Activity {
EditText age, height, weight;
String a, h, w;
Float age1, height1, weight1;
float bmi, cal;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.profinfo1view);

    TextView nameView = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.view_name);
    nameView.setText("Hello " + getIntent().getExtras().getString("name") + ",");
    TextView ageView = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.view_age);
    ageView.setText("Age: " + getIntent().getExtras().getString("age"));
    TextView heightView = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.view_height);
    heightView.setText("Your current height is " + getIntent().getExtras().getString("height") + " m.");
    TextView weightView = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.view_weight);
    weightView.setText("Your current weight is " + getIntent().getExtras().getString("weight") + " kg.");

    a = getIntent().getExtras().getString("age");
    h = getIntent().getExtras().getString("height");
    w = getIntent().getExtras().getString("weight");

    age1 = Float.valueOf(a).floatValue();
    height1 = Float.valueOf(h).floatValue();
    weight1 = Float.valueOf(w).floatValue();

    //bmi calculation
    bmi = (float) (weight1/Math.pow(height1, 2));
    TextView showresult = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.view_bmi);
    showresult.setText("Your BMI is " + Float.valueOf(bmi) + ".");

    //cal intake calculation
    cal = (float) (((655 + (9.6 * weight1) + (1.8 * height1) - (4.7 * age1)) * 1.2) - 550);
    TextView showcal = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.view_cal);
    showcal.setText("Your ideal daily calories intake is " + Float.valueOf(cal) + ".");

    //next button
    Button next2 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btn_next2);
    next2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent a = new Intent(ViewProf1.this, FoodDiary.class);
        startActivity(a);
    }

    });

    //back button
    Button back2 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btn_back2);
    back2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent a = new Intent(ViewProf1.this, ProfInfo1.class);
        startActivity(a);
    }

    });


}
```

the third activity:

```
public class CompareWeight extends Activity {

EditText weight;
String w;
Float weight1;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.compareweight);

    TextView weightView = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.test);
    weightView.setText("Your previous weight is " + getIntent().getExtras().getString("weight") + " kg.");

    w = getIntent().getExtras().getString("weight");

    weight1 = Float.valueOf(w).floatValue();
}
}
```

I only want to pass the weight value to the third activity.

Comment: You can only show one activity, for what You want to send a value to two activities? You can send a value with intent by starting the activity, the same way You can get the value if Your second activity get started

Comment: @Opiatefuchs in the first activity, i send 4 values but in the second I only want to send one to the second. I stripped the codes to only contain the value that I want and it still doesn't show the result.

Comment: post your code. It will help us to understand in detail.

Comment: @Vino I've added the codes. I couldn't pass the value to the third activity.

Comment: @elvegadro i posted the answer it should resolve your problem. look at that

Answer (score 1):

you can pass values to only one activity at a time.but if you want to pass weight value to third activity,then you can set it's value in first activity and retrieve in third activity.
So basically I mean

1. Put values that you want to pass in SecondActivity with the help of putExtra.
2. Set the sharedPrefernce variable.
3. startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

You can save the value in Shared Preferences and update the value o Button Click .Thus values will be available to other activities .

Answer (score 0):

Use `SharedPreferences` in `onPause` for current `Activity` as below and send the data to other activities as below:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() 
{
  super.onPause(); 
  SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();  
  editor.putString("SearchText",edt.getText().toString());
  editor.commit();

}
```

and in other two Activities, get the data from Shared Preferences as below:

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", 0);
 String edtText = preferences.getString("SearchText","");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get your string in the second activity like this :

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras != null) {
            item = extras.getString("myitempassed");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where in the code you are calling the third activity (CompareWeight).

When you start the CompareWeight activity, you can just pass in the weight value using intent extras like you did for the second activity.

If you don't have the weight value at that point, then you'll need to save it - @Avadhani Y has a good suggestion for using SharedPreferences.  Or you can use a SQLite DB to store your values.

Answer (score 0):

By use of PutExtra before startActivity.

Answer (score 0):

It is because in your `Second Activity` you just calling the Intent without passing any values in it,

**In Second Activity**

Replace the Intent

```
    Intent a = new Intent(ViewProf1.this, FoodDiary.class);
    startActivity(a);
```

With this

```
    Intent a = new Intent(ViewProf1.this, FoodDiary.class);
    a.putExtra("weight", weight1);
    startActivity(a);
```

Comment: there's another layout in between activity two and three that does not need the value, how do i pass the value through the activity because as you can see in my codes, the activity goes from ViewProf1 >> FoodDiary >> CompareWeight.

Comment: do the same, receive the weight in `FoodDairy` and pass the weight to `CompareWeight` Activity.

Comment: the logcat shows NullPointerException for CompareWeight.java.

Comment: if so you passing a null value from `FoodDairy` . Check there

Comment: I decided to skip FoodDiary to test the pass value between ProfInfo1 >> CompareWeight and it still gives me the NullPointerException. Is this because my datas are not kept in a database?

Comment: No If you pass data from `ViewProf1` then it should be on `FoodDiary`. Before sending check what data you sending from ProfInfo1. If there is any data then the  problem is in CompareWeight.